# JPA repository concept a general concept or coined by Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am learning Spring Data JPA, and I came across the term "**JPA repository**" (to be specific **Spring Data JPA repository**).  I want to understand if the term "**JPA repository**" is a *general concept* (like JPA - a standard specification) or coined by Spring Data project?

What exactly does "repository" in this context means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly does "repository" in this context means?

[*Repository*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) is one of the patterns introduced in [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html) (Martin Fowler, 2002). In the book, *Repository* defined as:

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a
> collection-like interface for accessing domain objects
>
> A system with a complex domain model often benefits from a layer, such as the one provided by *Data Mapper*, that isolates domain
> objects from details of the database access code. **In such systems it
> can be worthwhile to build another layer of abstraction over the
> mapping layer where query construction code is concentrated**. This
> becomes more important when there are a large number of domain classes
> or heavy querying. In these cases particularly, adding this layer
> helps minimize duplicate query logic.
>
> A Repository mediates between the domain and data mapping layers,
> acting like an in-memory domain object collection. **Client objects
> construct query specifications declaratively and submit them to
> Repository for satisfaction**. Objects can be **added** to and **removed** from
> the Repository, as they can from a simple collection of objects, and
> the mapping code encapsulated by the Repository will carry out the
> appropriate operations behind the scenes. **Conceptually, a Repository
> encapsulates the set of objects persisted in a data store and the
> operations performed over them, providing a more object-oriented view
> of the persistence layer.** Repository also supports the objective of
> achieving a clean separation and one-way dependency between the domain
> and data mapping layers.

## Further Reading

---

For more detailed discussion about Repository pattern, you should take a look at [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420) (Fowler, 2002) and [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) (Evans, 2003).